# Regex allow all except

Tags: regex, latin

I have a form, description, and I like to stop words like "www, http, //, @, .com, co.uk..."

I would like to stop all email and domains in this form but **allow** all types of characters spaces, comas, and latin characters with punctuation like "ç, ã, á, à..."

I have somethins like this

```
<code>
$().ready(function() {
// validate the description form when it is submitted
$("#descriptionform").validate();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9 \_,.]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Description field can not include e-mail and/or urls.");
$("#regForm").validate();
});
</code>
```

Could you help me please?
Thank you in advance

Comment: We cannot help you if you want to stop strings _like_ these. You need to be more specific. Can you provide an exhaustive list or a strict rule for what you want to exclude?

Comment: So you want to prevent people from writing "www" or "http" into your form? Don't you think that's a not-so-great idea? What do you *really* want to prevent? And why don't you check validity on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

This is a regex that will match if the input *doesn't* contain the character sequences you want to stop:

```
^(?!.*www)(?!.*http)(?!.*//)(?!.*@)(?!.*\.com)(?!.*co\.uk).+
```

Comment: Already try to put like this but doesen't work "return this.optional(element) || /^(?!.*www)(?!.*http)(?!.*//)(?!.*@)(?!.*\.com)(?!.*co\.uk)+$/i.test(value);"

Comment: @RAN You are missing a dot before the plus `+`. See edited answer

Comment: Already try this "return this.optional(element) || /^(?!.*www)(?!.*http)(?!.*//)(?!.*@)(?!.*\.com)(?!.*co\.uk).+$/i.test(value);" with the dot before the plus + and doesen't work. But if I remove "(?!.*//)" he works ok.